# How can I use intent to start same activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I am using intent to pass data from A activity to B activity. In B activity I have text view "name". when I proceed from activity A to B Intent is working fine. I have one more activity C And I want set the same text view which is in activity B with passing data from activity C to B

Comment: you want to send data from A to C??

Comment: Activity A to B and then C to B That means Class b has two intents

Comment: well, you open C Activity??

Answer (score 1):

Try to sent intent between your Activities like this..[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a text view in activity B and your are saying that you need to use the same text view in activity C. You cannot use the text view declared in another activity in the present activity. Declare a new text view and attach the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "onNewIntent" option in activity B.

You start activity B from A with startActivity(new intent with A data). Then from activity B you start activity C and do whatever. Now on activity C you can again start activity B with startActivity(new intent with C data). This will trigger a "onNewIntent" method in activity B and pass the intent data from C while keeping the intent data from A.

Example:
Activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("text", "data1");
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.putExtra("text", "data2");
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     String textA = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
 }

 @Override
 public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {
    super.onNewIntent(newIntent);
    String textB = newIntent.getStringExtra("text");
 }
```